Pandas Dataframe rolling mean of last 50 daily values differs from rolling("50D").mean()
I'm trying to find how the "50D" rolling mean is being calculated in the following example because really I cannot find the way.
import pandas as pd

values = [np.nan, -0.00076194, -0.01189744, -0.00062106, -0.00534628, -0.00331957, -0.00337944, 0.00630714, -0.00330637, -0.0045095 , 0.00064805, -0.01268343, -0.00614887, 0.00275657, -0.00440909, 0.00590626, -0.02339615, -0.01969567, 0.01092916, 0.01058356, -0.00758719, 0.00478345, -0.0023437 , 0.00288798, 0.0101454 , -0.0121736 , 0.01344621, -0.01383092, 0.00110947, -0.0004417 , -0.00088272, 0.00809808, -0.00034199, -0.00580861, 0.00621907, -0.00041045, -0.00292563, 0.00129668, -0.00427033, 0.00053285, 0.0021681 , -0.01402614, -0.00388071, 0.00153033, 0.00027945, -0.00899464, -0.00452222, -0.01700942, -0.00115979, -0.01157867, -0.01504971, 0.00732653, -0.01370921, 0.00867434, 0.00237124, 0.02349419, -0.01682703, 0.01467014, 0.01087479, -0.00393254, 0.00534539, -0.00678344, -0.00013054, -0.00503799, -0.00854087, 0.00295728, 0.00931616, 0.01194195, -0.00606532, -0.01017215, -0.003598 , -0.01083424, -0.00556437, -0.00348464, 0.006992 , 0.00278279, 0.00735125, 0.00506792, -0.00582055, -0.00053721, -0.00148132, 0.00828239, 0.00497641, 0.00082642, 0.00834549, 0.01315036, 0.00898724, -0.00256485, -0.00329441, 0.00332798, 0.01377536, -0.00836893, -0.0047126 , -0.00444542, 0.00688868, 0.01143246, 0.00478997, 0.00350752, -0.01044042, -0.01597756]
index = pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08', '2015-01-09', '2015-01-12', '2015-01-13', '2015-01-14', '2015-01-15', '2015-01-16', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-20', '2015-01-21', '2015-01-22', '2015-01-23', '2015-01-26', '2015-01-27', '2015-01-28', '2015-01-29', '2015-01-30', '2015-02-02', '2015-02-03', '2015-02-04', '2015-02-05', '2015-02-06', '2015-02-09', '2015-02-10', '2015-02-11', '2015-02-12', '2015-02-13', '2015-02-16', '2015-02-17', '2015-02-18', '2015-02-19', '2015-02-20', '2015-02-23', '2015-02-24', '2015-02-25', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-27', '2015-03-02', '2015-03-03', '2015-03-04', '2015-03-05', '2015-03-06', '2015-03-09', '2015-03-10', '2015-03-11', '2015-03-12', '2015-03-13', '2015-03-16', '2015-03-17', '2015-03-18', '2015-03-19', '2015-03-20', '2015-03-23', '2015-03-24', '2015-03-25', '2015-03-26', '2015-03-27', '2015-03-30', '2015-03-31', '2015-04-01', '2015-04-02', '2015-04-03', '2015-04-06', '2015-04-07', '2015-04-08', '2015-04-09', '2015-04-10', '2015-04-13', '2015-04-14', '2015-04-15', '2015-04-16', '2015-04-17', '2015-04-20', '2015-04-21', '2015-04-22', '2015-04-23', '2015-04-24', '2015-04-27', '2015-04-28', '2015-04-29', '2015-04-30', '2015-05-01', '2015-05-04', '2015-05-05', '2015-05-06', '2015-05-07', '2015-05-08', '2015-05-11', '2015-05-12', '2015-05-13', '2015-05-14', '2015-05-15', '2015-05-18', '2015-05-19', '2015-05-20'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=index, columns=["returns"])
df["rolling_50"] = df["returns"].rolling(50).mean()
df["rolling_50D"] = df["returns"].rolling("50D").mean()
df.dropna()

    returns     rolling_50  rolling_50D
2015-03-12  -0.015050   -0.002742   -0.002511
2015-03-13  0.007327    -0.002580   -0.002472
2015-03-16  -0.013709   -0.002616   -0.002203
2015-03-17  0.008674    -0.002430   -0.001415
2015-03-18  0.002371    -0.002276   -0.001653
2015-03-19  0.023494    -0.001740   -0.001294
2015-03-20  -0.016827   -0.002009   -0.001551
2015-03-23  0.014670    -0.001841   -0.001276
2015-03-24  0.010875    -0.001558   -0.000909
2015-03-25  -0.003933   -0.001546   -0.001098
2015-03-26  0.005345    -0.001452   -0.001232
2015-03-27  -0.006783   -0.001334   -0.001082
2015-03-30  -0.000131   -0.001214   -0.001459
2015-03-31  -0.005038   -0.001370   -0.001215
2015-04-01  -0.008541   -0.001452   -0.001483
2015-04-02  0.002957    -0.001511   -0.001388
2015-04-03  0.009316    -0.000857   -0.001105
2015-04-06  0.011942    -0.000224   -0.000998
2015-04-07  -0.006065   -0.000564   -0.001157
2015-04-08  -0.010172   -0.000979   -0.001279
2015-04-09  -0.003598   -0.000900   -0.001551
2015-04-10  -0.010834   -0.001212   -0.001841
2015-04-13  -0.005564   -0.001276   -0.001914
2015-04-14  -0.003485   -0.001404   -0.002047
2015-04-15  0.006992    -0.001467   -0.001734
2015-04-16  0.002783    -0.001168   -0.001672
2015-04-17  0.007351    -0.001290   -0.001528
2015-04-20  0.005068    -0.000912   -0.000997
2015-04-21  -0.005821   -0.001050   -0.001051
2015-04-22  -0.000537   -0.001052   -0.001109
2015-04-23  -0.001481   -0.001064   -0.001157
2015-04-24  0.008282    -0.001060   -0.000678
2015-04-27  0.004976    -0.000954   -0.000414
2015-04-28  0.000826    -0.000821   0.000082
2015-04-29  0.008345    -0.000779   0.000346
2015-04-30  0.013150    -0.000508   0.001033
2015-05-01  0.008987    -0.000269   0.001700
2015-05-04  -0.002565   -0.000347   0.001426
2015-05-05  -0.003294   -0.000327   0.001715
2015-05-06  0.003328    -0.000271   0.001566
2015-05-07  0.013775    -0.000039   0.001883
2015-05-08  -0.008369   0.000074    0.000998
2015-05-11  -0.004713   0.000057    0.001335
2015-05-12  -0.004445   -0.000062   0.000804
2015-05-13  0.006889    0.000070    0.000693
2015-05-14  0.011432    0.000479    0.001120
2015-05-15  0.004790    0.000665    0.001104
2015-05-18  0.003508    0.001075    0.001390
2015-05-19  -0.010440   0.000890    0.001104
2015-05-20  -0.015978   0.000802    0.000800

As you can see, after 50 rows (preceding rows are np.nan in the column "rolling_50") the value of the column "rolling_50" is different than the value in "rolling_50D". Shouldn't both have been calculated in the same way (because each row is a day) ?

Did you check df.rolling, under window, the difference between "int" and "timedelta"? For future ref, please provide a [mre]. E.g., a simple example like df = pd.DataFrame({'r': range(4)}, index=pd.date_range('2024-01-01', periods=4, freq='2d')).pipe(lambda x: x.assign(**{f'r{i}': x['r'].rolling(i).mean() for i in [2, '2d']})) would do. That also helps you see easier what both methods are doing. 1st takes 2 observations, 2nd takes a window of 2 consecutive days (days are missing, so we get mean of 1 day).

Last 50 rows != last 50 days. You have missing days in your index, which explains the difference of windows.
